# Why is it that non-programmers (like my family) can't understand me?

Tags: family, work-life-balance

I am 14 years old, I am from a not very developed country, which is far from such concepts as programming.

I really like programming, so I started doing it 3 years ago. During this time I gained experience in web full-stack programming, but my family does not understand my progress and says that I play with the computer, or that I'm scrolling social networks.

**How can I explain to them that I am not wasting my time?**

Comment: Is your family saying that you shouldn't be using the computer or using it so much?  Or are they just not understanding what you are learning?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [ips.se]! Could you tell us which region/culture/country you belong to, and what did they say when you tried explaining that? Answering these questions can help provide the best suitable answers.

Comment: Maybe just explain to (and show!) them what you're doing? And compare it to real life examples, websites they may be familiar with for one.

Comment: @DaveG they don't understand what i'm doing and think that I'm lying to them

Comment: @MiG I tried but they say if I don’t study well at school (it’s true) then how can I create websites, they think that only the smartest can do something useful behind the at computer